# How can I display an image from a Camera capture?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I followed a tutorial but it's not working, I got an empty space.

Here is my controller http://pastebin.com/PuUf4vy6

```
<img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{urlForImage(image)}}" style="height: 100px;" height="100px" width="100%" />
```

When I display the image path I got something like **file:///data/data/...**

Also already set the whitelist config

```
.config(function($compileProvider){
   $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
})
```

Comment: I'm also trying with http://pastebin.com/KsKSnWT1 none of them working

Comment: Have you tried following [this example](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/cordova-camera/)?

Comment: Yes, already tried that, it gives me the same result, a blank image, example http://imgur.com/Y2wAjwy

Comment: In your code you copy the image to another place. Can you see the image before you copy it?

Comment: No, in fact with the example from ionicframework that you gave me I only take the picture and add it to the view without copying or moving any file.